# Do you need Table Lock when you have multiple OLE DB connections inserting to the same table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis

SSIS is not really my forte. I noticed you have a table lock option on OLE DB destinations where the entire table becomes locked in what I assume is during the transaction of inserting data.

What happens if you have a flat file data source with a conditional split that is parsing out data into 5 or more OLE DB destinations that are targeting the same table with table lock on? Would each OLE DB destination get blocked by one another in this scenario if data is being fast loaded (inserted) into the destinations themselves?

I removed the table lock in my instance and everything seemed fine. It was splitting the data and inserting records at about 1 million records per minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table lock option facilitates minimal logging, reducing transaction log space requirements under certain circumstances.  Below are relevant excerpts from the [Prerequisites for Minimal Logging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190422.aspx) topic in the SQL Server Books Online.

> - The table is not being replicated.
> - Table locking is specified (using TABLOCK).
> - Table is not a memory-optimized table.
> - If the table has no indexes, data pages are minimally logged.
> - If the table has no clustered index but has one or more nonclustered    indexes, data pages are always minimally logged. How
>     index pages are    logged, however, depends on whether the table is
>     empty:
>
>   - If the table is empty, index pages are minimally logged.
>   - If table is non-empty, index pages are fully logged.
> - If you start with an empty table and bulk import the data in multiple    batches, both index and data pages are minimally logged
>     for the first    batch, but beginning with the second batch, only data
>     pages are    minimally logged.
> - If the table has a clustered index and is empty, both data and index    pages are minimally logged. In contrast, if a table has a
>     clustered    index and is non-empty, data pages and index pages are
>     both fully    logged regardless of the recovery model.

The table lock will block other processes using the table, including the other OLEDB Destinations within the SSIS package. You could set the Maximum Insert Commit Size to improve concurrency but with the consideration that file will be partially imported in the event of a failure.

Comment: Table has no indexes to improve insert speed. The recovery mode is simple, so filling up logs is not a huge issue. It sounds like the answer to my question is that table locking does block the other transactions so setting no table lock is a good option. I've imported quite a lot of data with no issues thus far with table lock off in simple recovery mode.